# OS Dev - undefined reference _kernel_main and undefined operator new(unsigned long)

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, operating-system

I tried doing something different today and it isn't working ): I have tried to follow some tutorials which I have linked below to develop a basic OS. I have changed the code a bit from the original tutorial which was procedural into a more Object-Oriented approach. I have checked over the original tutorial multiple times against my own code and I can't see anything that is different in terms of functionality. The only thing I think this could be would be something to do with me setting up my cross compiler?

### Repository

The repository where the files are stored is https://github.com/kingga/os

### Current Errors

When building with `call _kernel_main` commented out in `boot.asm` I get the following error:

```
Cleaning build directories.
Creating build and iso directories.
Building the bootloader.
Building the kernel.
Linking the kernel and bootloader.
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/9.2.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: build/kernel.o: in function `kernel_main()':
kernel.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Cleaning build directory.
```

When I uncomment `_kernel_main` as it is in this repository I get this error:

```
Cleaning build directories.
Creating build and iso directories.
Building the bootloader.
Building the kernel.
Linking the kernel and bootloader.
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/9.2.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: build/boot.o: in function `start':
boot.asm:(.mbHeader+0xe): undefined reference to `_kernel_main'
```

### Links

These are the tutorials I was following when building this. I used the CPlusPlus tutorial for the actual kernel and bootloader and OSDev for the cross compiler setup.

- [Tutorial Followed - CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zv07M4Gy/)
- [Cross-Compiler Tutorial - OSDev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)

Has anyone got any idea what I am doing wrong here? I am on Ubuntu 19.10 if that helps.

This is a fresh install of 19.10 on a VM using this provision script as well so you can see a complete setup of my machine:

https://github.com/kingga/personal-linux-provision-script

### Edit 1

Thanks to @Jester the linker problem is resolved through commit:
https://github.com/kingga/os/commit/49d3b55ed684a867d4a6321ad52f8c3268e8098a

### Edit 2

Thanks to everyone who has help me out.

Original issue for historic purposes: https://github.com/kingga/os/tree/stackoverflow-issue

Comment: You need to apply C++ name mangling to `kernel_main` which is **not** simply prepending an underscore. Alternatively define it as `extern "C"`. You will also need to link with the C++ runtime library that you specifically disabled by `-nostdlib -nodefaultlibs`. Obviously for `new` to work your OS needs to provide memory management functions that need to be invoked by the `new` operator. You should stick to static memory allocation until you have that. Do you insist on using C++?

Comment: @Jester I have implemented the extern "C" suggestion and it has now resolved the linker issues. Would you know any good resources for memory management functions or do you strongly suggest that I just scrap OO (I'd prefer not).

Comment: Your kernel is going to have to implement memory management at some point. Until you do, don't use the `new` operator.  That doesn't require that you abandon object oriented programming. When you do have something that can allocate memory then you can implement your own `operator new` function that uses it.  However you may find that using `new` to allocate objects doesn't give you the fine control over how objects are allocated that you need.